# Display/render/show view from controller

Tags: php

How can I show a view from a controller? Here is my code:

This is my **controller.php** file in `/var/www/html/application/controllers/controller.php`

```
public function __construct($controller) {
    if(!this->controller) {
        //show page from: /var/www/html/application/views/404.php
    }
}
```

Comment: You actually shouldn't. The way I read your code, it probably should be done at the bootstrap scope instead. You should check, if there exists class for a specific controller, and, if not, then the bootstrap should load the view, that is intended for 404 response.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i can understand from controller path, this is Codeigniter PHP Framework.

If so, you can load 404.php with code below:

```
$this->load->view('404');
```

Also there is a function named [show_404()](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html?highlight=#show_404) that trigers 404 error and loads corresponding view.

I strongly recommend you to read [Codeigniter Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/docs) from beginning.